# Why can companies charge money for their JDK Version despite the GNU GPL v2 of OpenJDK?

Tags: java, java-11

OpenJDK is released under the GNU General Public License v2.0 with a classpath exception. If you modify software under such license, you are obliged to release it under the GPL as well. 
So how come e.g. IBM can charge you for their modified version of the OpenJDK, which mostly includes bugfixes and minor optimizations by changing the existing OpenJDK (which means this doesn't fall under the classpath exception)? Don't they have to release it under the GPL as well which would make it free to use?

The only way I could explain this is, that they release the bug fixes and optimizations to OpenJDK delayed to their payed version, but I didn't find any reference stating this to be allowed.

Comment: Technically speaking a software is **not** under any license. When the author **distributes** it to someone they can decide whichever license they want. In other words the JDK Project **can** license openjdk to IBM under a proprietary license that allows IBM to relicense it however they want. Whether this happened or not I don't know and it may be impossible to determine unless you are part of either the JDK Project or IBM. Just because some software is available with a certain license does not mean that the author may not distribute it with other licenses at their discretion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software licences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in the GNU GPL v2 (or v3) license that prohibits you from charging money for the code or the binary files.

[Read here](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.html#DoesTheGPLAllowMoney) for clarification.

The only thing the license does not permit you to do, is limit those you sold the code to from giving it away to others.